# I'm trying to get a token from API login, but I get an Object null prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, fetch-api

I am implementing API login with node js and JavaScript. I'm trying to get a token, but the console says:

> Object: null prototype as shown below.

```
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://URL(sensitive information)',
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

Below is my code.

```
export const startKakaoLogin = (req, res) => {
  const baseUrl = "https://kauth.kakao.com/oauth/authorize?";
  const config = {
    client_id: process.env.KA_ID,
    redirect_uri: process.env.KA_RE,
    response_type: "code",
    prompt: "login",
  };
  const params = new URLSearchParams(config).toString();
  const finalUrl = `${baseUrl}&${params}`;
  return res.redirect(finalUrl);
};


export const finishKakaoLogin = async (req, res) => {
  const baseUrl = "https://kauth.kakao.com/oauth/token";
  const config = {
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    client_id: process.env.KA_ID,
    redirect_uri: process.env.KA_RE,
    code: req.query.code,
  };
  const params = new URLSearchParams(config).toString();
  const finalUrl = `${baseUrl}&${params}`;
  const tokenRequest = await fetch(finalUrl, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
    },
    body: finalUrl,
  });
  console.log(tokenRequest);
};
```

Additionally, In the reference, 'curl' was used, but I used 'fetch', did I do something wrong?

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: kauth.kakao.com
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8

curl -v -X POST "https://kauth.kakao.com/oauth/token" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
 -d "grant_type=authorization_code" \
 -d "client_id=${REST_API_KEY}" \
 --data-urlencode "redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}" \
 -d "code=${AUTHORIZE_CODE}"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting to get from the endpoint? You're just logging the [Response object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) right now and are seeing a representation of its internals.

To get e.g. the text from the response body, you'll need to parse it too, here with [`Response#text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text):

```
const text = await tokenRequest.text();
console.log(text);
```

If you're looking for JSON, then use [`Response#json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json).

```
const data = await tokenRequest.json();
console.log(data);
```

Be sure to check that the response's error code is what you expect, though, with e.g. [`tokenRequest.ok`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok).

Comment: json(); When I do this I get `return Body.Promise.reject(new FetchError(invalid json response body at ${_this2.url} reason: ${err.message}, invalid-json))` this error pops up Also, text() doesn't display anything on the console.

Comment: Well, the question stands: what are you expecting to get from the endpoint? How does the reference follow up from making that `curl` request?

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{
    "token_type":"bearer",
    "access_token":"${ACCESS_TOKEN}",
    "expires_in":43199,
    "refresh_token":"${REFRESH_TOKEN}",
    "refresh_token_expires_in":25184000,
    "scope":"account_email profile"
}`

If the response is successful, it should appear like this.
Here is an address for your reference.
https://developers.kakao.com/docs/latest/en/kakaologin/rest-api

Comment: Right. If getting the response JSON is your goal, then you should just use `await r.json()` as described above. If it fails, then there's something else wrong (e.g. the remote end didn't send you JSON).

Comment: But I have already called the JSON file.  like this `app.use(express.json());`
And I added more start code above.

Comment: Your express configuration is not related at all to how you use `fetch()`.